# $.css() not working with :hover and :active psuedo-classes

Tags: jquery, css

I am wondering why the `button:hover` and `button:active` is not working when using `$.css()`

```
button {
    background: #781111;
    color: white;
}
```

```
<button>test</button>
```

```
$('button:hover').css({
    'background':'#fe2000'
});

$('button:active').css({
    'background':'#d50d04'
});
```

The button still appears in the same way when hovering and clicking it. Is there another way of doing this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EneH7/)

Comment: you can't do that... using jQuery we can set styles for a element... not to any psuedo classes

Comment: *psuedo classes* like `:active`, `:visited`, `:hover` etc.. are inaccessible and cannot be manipulated via JavaScript or jQuery. You can however, load a separate stylesheet containing different definitions within.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ this can help you.

Comment: must be a quick solution via jQuery (and yes there is a REASON for jQuery)...

Comment: Please read the answers we've given you, as there are two jQuery solutions that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an all jQuery method

```
var $this = $('button')
    .on('mouseout mouseup', function() {
        // Normal
        $this.css('background', initialColor);
    })
    .mouseover(function() {
        // Hover
        $this.css('background', '#ff0000');
    })
    .mousedown(function() {
        // Active
        $this.css('background', '#00ff00');
    }),
    initialColor = $this.css('background');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EneH7/2/)

Comment: = PE PE PE PERFECT ! :-)

Comment: @user3301364 you still didn't answer why would you need that when your CSS is fully cross browser. Better then would be to toggle some classes instead, applying specific CSS rules

Answer (score 5):

You can use pure css instead:

```
button:hover {
    background: #fe2000
}

button:active {
    background: #d50d04
}
```

I'd suggest you to use CSS instead of javascript to achieve any task that can be done by both ways.

Comment: Yes, he can use pure CSS indeed, but I'd rather help him with his jQuery approach instead, as he wants it in jQuery.

Comment: Which could be the reason to use jQuery here? Could it be an XY problem?! So why would you need to target any pseudo class using jQuery? Anyway, pseudo classes are not part of the DOM, so you are out of luck

Comment: @user3301364 Yes, `there is a reason for jQuery` but not in this case. If you curious about how to achieve something similar using `jQuery`, then you can check out @stigok answer

Answer (score 1):

Its best way to apply css

```
button:hover {
    background: #fe2000
}

button:active {
    background: #d50d04
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the hover and active selectors like that, you should use the events `$.hover` and `$.focus`.

Comment: What are this: `$.hover` and `$.active`?

Comment: I'd like to refer you to [**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [**.focus()**](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) (wrote the latter wrong).

Comment: So this is: `$.fn.hover()` and `$.fn.focus()` ;)

Comment: Indeed, just easier to write this way :-)